# How use webpack plugin to only one entry

Tags: plugins, webpack

I want to use in webpack multiple entries using the same file, but passing a variable.

My idea is use the webpack.definePlugin to each entry.

Example:

```
{
  entry: {
    file1: 'myfile.js',
    file2: 'myfile.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]/myjs.js'
  }
}
```

And I set the plugins:

```
{
   plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        MYVARTOFILE: 'a',
        filename: 'file1/myjs.js' // I want to make something like this
     }),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        MYVARTOFILE: 'b',
        filename: 'file2/myjs.js' // I want to make something like this
     })
   ]
}
```

Or if is possible passing a variable to each entry in a different way.
If is possible to:

```
  entry: {
    file1: 'myfile.js?variable=a',
    file2: 'myfile.js?variable=b',
  }
```

And get in my file this variable,.